# В каких случаях триггер перестает работать?

Tags: sql, oracle

Столкнулся с тем, что в какой-то момент триггер перестал работать.
Какие действия могут к этому привести?

Comment: триггеры можно включать и выключать, из интерфейса вашего иде или коммандой